# how to fetch first value from csv for all api then second value from csv for all api

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I have a scenario in which all the API should fetch a first value from csv file then after second value from csv, right now it is accepting one by one values from csv.[image]

In the screenshot, Email and password should be fetched first test1@gmail.com for login with email1, email2,email3 then after it should be fetched test2@gmail.com for email1, email2,email3

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, if you're using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) the options are in:

1. Each user reads next line on each iteration, like:

   - user 1, iteration 1 - first line
   - user 1, iteration 2 - second line
   - user 2, iteration 1 - third line
   - user 1, iteration 3 - fourth line
   - etc.
2. Every user has "individual" access to the CSV file, like:

   - user 1, iteration 1 - first line
   - user 1, iteration 2 - second line
   - user 2, iteration 1 - first line
   - user 2, iteration 2 - second line,
   - etc.

This behaviour is controllable via ["Sharing Mode" setting of the CSV Data Set Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/csv-data-set-config-in-sharing-mode-made-easy/)

If you want more flexibility you will have to go for [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, You always help me in JMeter