# I have Multiple login API in single thread, I need to fetch different value from CSV file for each API

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

Scenario : I need to test Login API with different Email ID and Password, I have created CSV file and put different emails in it, now while running the script all API are taking only first email from CSV.
I need to fetch first email for first API then second email to second API from CSV.

Screen shot : here after running the script Request1 should get test1@gmail.com then Request2 should fetch test2@gmail.com and so on.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I might be suffering from a form of a mental fatigue, however I believe [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66203767/how-to-fetch-first-value-from-csv-for-all-api-then-second-value-from-csv-for-all) I did mention how does CSV Data Set Config work, it reads **next value on next iteration**, if you want to read the next value within the bounds of the current iteration - you will have to switch to the [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead)

Examples:

- `${__CSVRead(Users.csv,0)}` - read a value from 1st column from "Users.csv" file
- `${__CSVRead(Users.csv,1)}` - read a value from 2nd column from "Users.csv" file
- `${__CSVRead(Users.csv,next)}` - proceed to next row

Demo:

[image]

More information and another useful feature: [How to Pick Different CSV Files at JMeter Runtime](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-pick-different-csv-files-at-jmeter-runtime)

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmitri, As always you again helped me to solve this.